# Confused About Joins in RStudio Using merge()

Tags: r, dataframe, join

I have two data sets I want to merge in R so I can run regressions on them.

First Table (df1):

| Facility.ID | County | Stars |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Duval | 3 |
| 10002 | Duval | 2 |
| 10003 | Hillsborough | 1 |

Second Table (df2):

| County | Unemployment | Income |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Duval | 4 | 45000 |
| Hillsborough | 3 | 30000 |

And I want it to become this (df_ord):

| Facility.ID | County | Stars | Unemployment | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Duval | 3 | 4 | 45000 |
| 10002 | Duval | 2 | 4 | 45000 |
| 10003 | Hillsborough | 1 | 3 | 30000 |

I've tried every variation of the merge function I can come up with and no dice. New rows with NA values for df1 and the actual values for df2 are created (or vice versa) or df_ord will have 0 observations after the merge.

```
df1 <- structure(list(Facility.ID = 10001:10003, County = c("Duval", "Duval", "Hillsborough"), Stars = 3:1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
df2 <- structure(list(County = c("Duval", "Hillsborough"), Unemployment = 4:3, Income = c(45000L, 30000L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df_ord <- merge(df1, df2, by = "County", all = FALSE)
df_ord <- merge(df1, df2, by = "County", all = TRUE)
df_ord <- merge(df1, df2, by = "County", all.x = TRUE)
df_ord <- merge(df1, df2, by = "County", all.y = TRUE)
```

The dplyr joins give me the same problem. What kind of join should I be doing? Is what I want even possible with a join?

For Example with:

```
df_ord <- merge(df1, df2, by = "County", all = TRUE)
```

I will get:

| County | Facility.ID | Stars | Unemployment | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Duval | 10001 | 3 | NA | NA |
| Duval | 10002 | 2 | NA | NA |
| Duval | NA | NA | 4 | 45000 |
| Hillsborough | 10003 | 1 | NA | NA |
| Hillsborough | NA | NA | 3 | 30000 |

Comment: all of your attempts give me your desired outcome, except county for row 3 should be "Hillsborough" instead?

Comment: Yeah that's a typo, let me fix that. I'll add some example tables of what I get.

Comment: I still don't see an issue, the only difference is the order of columns.

Comment: I just added an example of what happens. It seems to me that there may be something different about my dataset that is making R act up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm livid. In the df2 dataset each of the values for "County" have a space after them, while df1 does not. This causes R to treat them as different values. Thank you everyone for your help, and sorry for wasting your time.

https://tenor.com/view/blade-runner2049-agent-k-mad-kicking-chair-agent-kblade-runner2049-gif-17059821

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 %>%
  full_join(df2, by="County")
```

left_join will also work and your answers also work!

Comment: Huh. Yeah with my example tables and rawr's code it works. But with my datasets it does not.